# What is the best practice when using .ultraThinMaterial on dark mode using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The iOS app I am making supports dark mode, and I am using .ultraThinMaterial in the background of my navigation bar for better contrast and visibility. While it looks amazing in light mode, the dark mode version seems to have this white hue to it which looks, in my opinion, kind of cheesy.

I'm looking for a solution that I could implement for dark mode only, to avoid it looking like this:

[image: Light Mode Screenshot]

[image: Dark Mode Screenshot]

The pictures don't do it justice for how bad it looks on a physical iPhone Screen, at least on my monitor

Here is the code that uses the .ultraThinMaterial:

```
Color.clear
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
            .blur(radius: 20)
            .saturation(0.0)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .frame(height:70+80)
            .offset(y: 50)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
struct ContentView: View {

@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        if colorScheme == .light{
            Color.clear
                .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                .blur(radius: 20)
                .saturation(0.0)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .frame(height:70+80)
                .offset(y: 50)
        }
    }//: ZSTACK
}
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, however I want to keep a similar look that it slowly makes the underlying views invisible, not get rid of the background completely if the device is in dark mode.